TypeScript Optional Parameters in Mapped Types are Incorrectly Required
I’m working on a TypeScript utility that allows registering events with a defined schema and emitting them while enforcing strict type checking for parameters.
The issue arises with optional parameters defined in the schema. I expect that when a key is marked optional, it should be possible to omit it entirely. However, TypeScript still raises an error when I omit the key during event emission.
Here is the minimal reproduction of my issue:
type ParameType<T> = {
  regexSnippet: string
  parse?: (value: string) => any
  type: T
}

const ParameterTypes = {
  "string": <ParameType<string>>{ regexSnippet: "\\w+" },
  "number": <ParameType<number>>{ regexSnippet: "\\d+", parse: parseInt },
  "string?": <ParameType<undefined | string>>{ regexSnippet: "\\w*" },
  "number?": <ParameType<undefined | number>>{ regexSnippet: "\\d*", parse: parseInt },
} as const

type ParamsTypeMap = typeof ParameterTypes
type ParamsTypeKeys = keyof ParamsTypeMap
type ParamsSchema = { [name: string]: ParamsTypeKeys }
type ParamsSchemaToObject<T extends ParamsSchema> = { [K in keyof T]: ParamsTypeMap[T[K]]["type"] }

type Settings = {
  parameters: ParamsSchema
}

class Test<T extends { [name: string]: Settings } = {}> {
  protected events: T = {} as T

  registerEvent<K extends string, V extends Settings>(
    eventname: K,
    settings: V
  ): asserts this is Test<T & { [keyname in K]: V }> {
    // ...
  }

  emit<K extends keyof T>(
    eventname: K,
    parameters: ParamsSchemaToObject<T[K]["parameters"]>
  ): any {
    // ...
  }
}

const test: Test = new Test()

test.registerEvent("prmtst", { parameters: { a: "number", b: "number?", c: "string" } })
test.emit("prmtst", { a: 1, b: 2, c: "str" }) // OK
test.emit("prmtst", { a: 1, c: "str" })       // Error, but `b` is optional

In the example above, the parameter b is marked as optional (number?), but TypeScript still throws an error when I omit it entirely.
Question:
How can I modify the ParamsSchemaToObject type so that optional keys like b can be safely omitted when emitting events?

Do you want something to be optional if its type name ends in ? Or if it includes undefined?

the problem is that if I add ? to [K in keyof T]? all parameters become optional, but if the parameters can only be undefined I am forced to define the key as { key: undefined }

Sorry, you're not answering my question. Let me start again: how do I detect that you want something to be optional? How do I know that "string?" is optional? Is it because of that "?" in the name? or is it the undefined in ParameType<string | undefined>? I'm trying to figure out how to make this programmatic.

(see prev comment). Assuming it's the undefined, then maybe this approach is what you're looking for? Note that there are two different pieces of it: one is allowing undefined-accepting properties to be optional, the other is allowing {}-accepting parameters to be optional. If that meets your needs I'll write an answer explaining (but please thoroughly test my suggestion first). If not, what am I missing?

Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do.
One more question, if I change from undefine to never, is it possible to make this code more user-friendly?

No, never will be absorbed into unions (e.g., ParameType<string | never> is exactly the same as ParameType<string>) so if you do that it'll be impossible to distinguish optional from required. You could maybe use the "question-mark-in-the-name" approach instead but I don't see why that's any more user-friendly. I won't worry about this aspect of it and I'll just write an answer.

There are two separate things you're trying to accomplish.

One is that whenever you have a property that accepts undefined, you'd like that property to be optional. For that, we can write a utility type UndefToOptional<T> that converts a type like {a: string | undefined, b: number} into a type like {a?: string, b: number}. The straightforward way to do that is to use the Partial utility type to make every property optional, and then intersect it with a key-remapped type that keeps just the non-undefined-accepting properties as required:
type UndefToOptional<T> = Partial<T> &
{ [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K] }

type X = UndefToOptional<{ a: string | undefined, b: number }>;
//   ^? type X = Partial<{ a: string | undefined; b: number; }> & { b: number; }

It might not be obvious that this is the type you want, but it works. A more complicated definition is:
type UndefToOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  (x: undefined extends T[K] ? { [P in K]?: T[K] } : { [P in K]: T[K] }) => void } extends
  Record<keyof T, (x: infer V) => void> ? { [K in keyof V]: V[K] } : never

type X = UndefToOptional<{ a: string | undefined, b: number }>;
//   ^? type X = { a?: string | undefined; b: number; }

You can see that the output type is prettier. What I'm doing here is effectively the same as the Transform union type to intersection type approach, where we intersect a bunch of one-property objects, each one either partial or required. So for {a: string | undefined, b: number} we end up with {a?: string} & {b: number} and then combine those in a single mapped type with {[K in keyof V]: V[K]}.  I don't know that it's worth describing exactly how and why this works. If you want a simpler implementation, use the intersection above.
Now we can just modify ParamsSchemaToObject so that it uses UndefToOptional:
type ParamsSchemaToObject<T extends ParamsSchema> =
  UndefToOptional<{ [K in keyof T]: ParamsTypeMap[T[K]]["type"] }>


The second thing is that you want the emit() method to allow the second parameter to be optional if it accepts a weak-typed object. A weak object has all optional properties.  TypeScript doesn't make it easy to have a parameter be either optional or required via a switch. You can do it if you give the function a tuple-typed rest parameter which can then be either a regular (required) tuple or one with optional elements. So let's define WeakToOptionalTuple<T>:
type WeakToOptionalTuple<T> = {} extends T ? [T?] : [T]

A weak object is one to which the empty object {} is assignable. If T is weak, then WeakOptionalTuple is a single-element tuple with an optional T element; otherwise it's a single-element tuple with a required T element.  And then we can write emit() as
emit<K extends keyof T>(
  eventname: K, ...[parameters]: WeakToOptionalTuple<
    ParamsSchemaToObject<T[K]["parameters"]>
  >): any {
  // ...
}

where the last parameter is a destructured rest parameter named parameters, and its type is that optional-or-required tuple.

Let's test it out:
test.registerEvent("str", { parameters: { a: "string?" } });
test.registerEvent("prmtst", { parameters: { a: "number", b: "number?", c: "string" } });
test.emit("prmtst", { a: 1, c: "str" }); // okay
test.emit("str", {}); // okay
test.emit("str"); // okay
test.emit("prmtst"); // error

If you look at the call signature for test.emit("prmtst", ⋯), it is (eventname: "prmtst", parameters: { a: number; b?: number; c: string;}): any, whereas the call signature for test.emit("str", ⋯) is (eventname: "str", parameters?: { a?: string }): any, so you can see that the properties and parameters are optional in exactly the cases you care about.
Playground link to code
